# create video from images of camera roll - iOS sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, avassetwriter

I have used following code to create video from the images.

This code works fine when i select the image from camera roll which is downloaded from web or the screenshot but the image selected which are taken from camera shows zoomed in in the movie.

I don't know what is wrong with the images of camera.

can anyone please help me resolve this issue.

```
       -(IBAction)createV:(id)sender
    {
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory()
                                stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString *videoOutputPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test_output.mp4"];

CGSize imageSize = [DatabaseAccess getusersetsize];

double nospf =[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"duration"] intValue];
NSUInteger fps = 10;

NSMutableArray *imageArray;// = [DatabaseAccess getimagelist:@"select imgname from tbl_userimage"];
NSArray* imagePaths = [DatabaseAccess getimagelist:@"select imgname,strftime('%d-%m-%Y', tdate) as tdate from tbl_userimage"];
imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:imagePaths.count];
int i=0;
for (NSString* path in [imagePaths valueForKey:@"image"] )
{
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"disdate"])
    {
        CGSize imgsize = [DatabaseAccess getusersetsize];

        //[imageArray addObject:[[DatabaseAccess drawText:[[imagePaths valueForKey:@"date"] objectAtIndex:i] inImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[DatabaseAccess documentsPathForFileName:path]] atPoint:CGPointMake(imgsize.width-250,imgsize.height-60) ] fixOrientation]];
        [imageArray addObject:[DatabaseAccess drawText:[[imagePaths valueForKey:@"date"] objectAtIndex:i] inImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[DatabaseAccess documentsPathForFileName:path]] atPoint:CGPointMake(imgsize.width-250,imgsize.height-60) ]];
    }
    else
    {
        [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[DatabaseAccess documentsPathForFileName:path]]];
        NSLog(@"%@",path);
       // [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:path]];
    }
    i++;
}
[self exportImages:imageArray asVideoToPath:videoOutputPath withFrameSize:imageSize framesPerSecond:fps numberOfSecondsPerFrame:nospf];
   }






   - (void)exportImages:(NSMutableArray *)imageArray asVideoToPath:(NSString *)videoOutputPath withFrameSize:(CGSize)imageSize framesPerSecond:(NSUInteger)fps numberOfSecondsPerFrame:(double)numberOfSecondsPerFrame {

NSError *error = nil;
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory()
                                stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];


NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];


if ([fileMgr removeItemAtPath:videoOutputPath error:&error] != YES)
    NSLog(@"Unable to delete file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);


//////////////     end setup    ///////////////////////////////////

NSLog(@"Start building video from defined frames.");

AVAssetWriter *videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:
                              [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoOutputPath] fileType:AVFileTypeMPEG4 error:&error];
NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);

NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:imageSize.width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:imageSize.height], AVVideoHeightKey,
                               nil];

AVAssetWriterInput* videoWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput
                                        assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                        outputSettings:videoSettings];


AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor
                                                 assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:videoWriterInput
                                                 sourcePixelBufferAttributes:nil];

NSParameterAssert(videoWriterInput);
NSParameterAssert([videoWriter canAddInput:videoWriterInput]);
videoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
[videoWriter addInput:videoWriterInput];

//Start a session:
[videoWriter startWriting];
[videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];

CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;

//convert uiimage to CGImage.
int frameCount = 0;
//double numberOfSecondsPerFrame = 6;
double frameDuration = fps * numberOfSecondsPerFrame;

//for(VideoFrame * frm in imageArray)
NSLog(@"**************************************************");
for(UIImage * img in imageArray)
{



    //UIImage * img = frm._imageFrame;
    buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[img CGImage]];

    BOOL append_ok = NO;
    int j = 0;
    while (!append_ok && j < 30) {
        if (adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData)  {
            //print out status:
            NSLog(@"Processing video frame (%d,%lu)",frameCount,(unsigned long)[imageArray count]);
            CMTime frameTime = CMTimeMake(frameCount,(int32_t) numberOfSecondsPerFrame);
            //CMTime frameTime = CMTimeMake(frameCount*frameDuration,(int32_t) fps);
            // NSLog(@"%@",frameTime);
            append_ok = [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:frameTime];
            if(!append_ok){
                NSError *error = videoWriter.error;
                if(error!=nil) {
                    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@,%@.", error, [error userInfo]);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("adaptor not ready %d, %d\n", frameCount, j);
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
        }
        j++;
    }
    if (!append_ok) {
        printf("error appending image %d times %d\n, with error.", frameCount, j);
    }
    frameCount++;
}
NSLog(@"**************************************************");

//Finish the session:
[videoWriterInput markAsFinished];
[videoWriter finishWriting];
NSLog(@"Write Ended");
[self playMovie:videoOutputPath];
}




- (CVPixelBufferRef) pixelBufferFromCGImage: (CGImageRef) image {

// CGSize size = CGSizeMake(400, 200);

CGSize size = [DatabaseAccess getusersetsize];

NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                         nil];
CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;

CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                      size.width,
                                      size.height,
                                      kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB,
                                      (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) options,
                                      &pxbuffer);
if (status != kCVReturnSuccess){
    NSLog(@"Failed to create pixel buffer");
}

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
void *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer);

CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata, size.width,
                                             size.height, 8, 4*size.width, rgbColorSpace,
                                             kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
//kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);
NSParameterAssert(context);
//CGContextConcatCTM(context, frameTransform);
CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0));
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGImageGetWidth(image),
                                       CGImageGetHeight(image)), image);
CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
CGContextRelease(context);

CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);

return pxbuffer;
 }
```

Comment: Which size you have select to create video while your are selecting images from camera & from library? because your code seems correct. i have use same code .. and its working perfect for both images..

Comment: @iphoneDev thanks for comment... I have used the screen resolution as the size, if its iPhone 3.5 without retina than 320x480 ect. you can say its the same size as the image size. and i checked at all places i am getting size as defined...

Comment: the video is created correct but the images of camera are zoomed in, that's the only issue.. the size of video is also as defined

Comment: you can resize or crop image related to video size before adding it to video replace your code with this                                                  for(UIImage * img in array){UIImage *tempImg =  [img imageScaleAndCropToMaxSize:kFrameSize];
buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[tempImg CGImage]];
append_ok = NO;                                                           
kFrameSize = size of your video file.                                     hope this will help you.

Comment: @iphoneDev where i can get imageScaleAndCropToMaxSize

Comment: Check this [link](https://github.com/MSiOSDeveloper/basic-structure/blob/master/BasicStructure/Library/Extensions/UIImageExtras/UIImage%2BResize.m) for image resize or scaling

Comment: @iphoneDev thanks dear, resize worked for me, but still i don't know what was wrong without it.. :)

Comment: Actually its issue with image size. if you take image from camera then its size is approx. 1936 × 2592 so while creating image it will take this size.. so your image is zoomed out.. so we have use scaling image.. it will resize your image relative to your video size.. it also works for small size image issue. cause in small size image is stretched...

Comment: thanks for this code, it works fine but i have one quarry, can you tell me what is DatabaseAccess?

Comment: @jayjayesh It is a controller which has the common methods to access data from table.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved image zoomed in issue using this code

```
-(UIImage*)scaleImage:(UIImage*)image toSize:(CGSize)newSize 
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

resize `UIImage` before converting it to `CGImage`, 
make sure you resize `image.width` in multiple of 16.

```
CGSize your_size = CGSizeMake(1600, 800);
UIImage *tempImg = [self scaleImage:img toSize:your_size..];
buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[tempImg CGImage]];
```