# Convert Video from images with page curl effect / animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avassetwriter

I am using `AVAssetWriter` and its method  to convert array of images to video as per below method,

[create video from images of camera roll - iOS sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25863731/create-video-from-images-of-camera-roll-ios-sdk)

It will create a video with simple next to next image display. 
But I want to create a video with all the images with page curl animation is there any way to do that or any other method for the same ?

Thanks in advance.

-Austin

Comment: No you can't compose video using apple provide ready made animations. I recommend you create custom animations, implement it, and while at time of video creation you will get easily series of images frames and time as well. Happy coding.

Comment: @Tirth thanks for the comment, I have tried that also but it will not give me exact animated position or view at the time of screen capturing if I'll use CGContext for image capturing.
-Thanks

 Do you have any other code for that?

Comment: My friend i'm not saying anywhere you should do screen capturing using CGContext yeah any other. If you do so your application will be crash after some time and luckily if not crashed you could be faced unhanded data. Also screen capturing is bad way. I recommend, if you achieve add images in video and successfully compose it then why not series of same image animation you can compose in video. Right now some application in market doing same like talking bade chote, talking tom application.

Comment: Okay I got your point.
I have Google it but not able to find code to add animation in video with images...

Comment: Hmmm. many people implemented it but not shared code.

Comment: @Austin if you get solution for this problem then please share.